# Antonym for "infix" ("outfix"?)

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

**infix**: implant or insert firmly in something, as in *the particles of mercury will infix themselves in the structure of the other metal*

How about the opposite? Is there something called *outfix*? I.e. encapsulate or surround firmly around something, as in *the particles of mercury will* <s>outfix</s> *themselves around the structure of the other metal*

Comment: Do you really need *infix* in the first example? It seems to me that *fix* will work in either sentence.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Maybe not in that example (which was just what Google came up with for "infix"), but i would still want a way to distinguish the verbs in general. Do you have a better examples?

Comment: *Infix* is usually paired with *prefix* and *suffix*. I can't think of an example where *fix around* is not used for fixing around.

Comment: @AndrewLeach So *aroundfix*?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping the source language consistent (Latin) with *circumfix,* but I'd be surprised if that has any traction.

Comment: @AndrewLeach At least that is actually an existing word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach By looking *circumfix* up, I found *adfix*. That would work.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/359791/14666